# What's the best way to deal with a tangle of membership types, currencies and taking donations on membership contribution pages?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, currency

I am managing the CiviCRM setup for a membership organiziation that is about to enter a campaign drive.

In the past, it has not been possible to select currency as one of the options in a contribution page or price set and so I set up 6 different contribution pages, like this:

- Institutional membership - USD
- Institutional membership - EUR
- Institutional membership - GBP
- Individual membership - USD
- Individual membership - EUR
- Individual membership - GBP

And to make that possible with only two member types and the different values for each currency, I use price sets. It is a lot of juggling (especially with language translations layered on top), but has basically worked for several years.

Now they would like to solicit donations at the same time. The "Contribution amounts" section cannot be enabled when using a membership price set. In the past, I could add additional fields to the price set with fixed donation amounts, though write-ins were not very realistic. However, since the recent interface change to the prices sets screen, any new field except text/numeric requires setting a membership type, so I can't seem to set additional donations as part of the prices set.

All of this has become so tangled that I thought it might be time to ask the question, "what is the current best way to deal with accepting different currencies while also soliciting donations on a membership contribution page?" Does anyone have an example solution to either or both of these problems?

I wonder if Form-builder might be at a state to be useful here?

We're running CiviCRM 5.66.1 on Wordpress 6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to

> since the recent interface change to the prices sets screen, any new field except text/numeric requires setting a membership type, so I can't seem to set additional donations as part of the prices set

Maybe i am misconstruing the issue but I had no problems just now on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/price/field/edit?action=preview&sid=9&reset=1&context=field (will disappear in a few hours), setting up a Memb based price set with an additional Contribution 'select' field. I simply opted not to choose a Memb Type for those options and it saved  fine.

[image]

and

[image]

Is there something I am not factoring in that is causing you problems?

Comment: Sidenote @petednz: I see your html labels are back when editing the price options. I've put up a PR for it: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28090

Comment: well spotted - and sorted @demerit

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. It seems that something was broken with my older price sets and various things were misbehaving. I have created new prices sets and all is well at this basic level. I still wish there were a cleaner way to deal with multiple currencies. Ah well.